# How to determine number of values returned by a function

Tags: go, reflection

How can I get a function's return value length, the effect will be similar to below:

```
func Foo() (int, int){
    ...
}
func Bar() (int, float, bool, string, error){
    ...
}
n1 := getReturnLength(Foo) // shall be 2
n2 := getReturnLength(Bar) // shall be 5
```

How shall I do to implement the `getReturnLength` function or something equal?

Comment: or I can use something similar to recive the return:
```go
s := make([]interface{}, 0)
s... = Foo() // it's invalid now
```

Comment: or in another word,how to pack function's return values into a array or slice?

Comment: reflection can do this, but the real question is: why would you need this?

Comment: I wanna to use this way to write a regular err check method, rather than check err in every function call,maybe more graceful way I don't know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve it using the reflect package.

```
reflect.TypeOf(Foo).NumOut()
```

You can learn about reflect package here https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type

Answer (score -2):

You should not use reflection for putting the return values of a function into a slice. Rather, you should return a slice iterate over the result range

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
)

func foo(num int) []int {

    s := make([]int, num)

    for i := 1; i <= num; i++ {
        s[i-1] = i
    }

    return s
}

func main() {
    r := foo(5)

       // Will run 0 times if len(r) == 0
       // Obviously, if you need 1+
       // results, you need to guard this
      // with something like 
      //   if len(r) < 1...
    for i := range r {
        fmt.Printf("Hello, %d!\n", r[i])
    }

    // Or, simpler
    for i, v := range foo(5) {
        fmt.Printf("Index %d => Value %d\n", i, v)
    }
}
```